# Team Foundation Server Check In Error

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I am getting the following error when trying to check in my project;

> TF10123: The path '$/My
> Project/SourceCode/AdminView/bin/MicrosG�L��pNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll'
> contains the character ''. Remove the '' and try again.

Now the error is referencing another project in the source control and not the one I am trying to check in?

Any ideas why its throwing this up?

I've tried removing this from my source control projects as a temp fix. i.e. doing the following;

> Select the Team Explorer tab from the Solution Explorer
>
> Select the Connect to Team Projects (little plug button)
>
> Select 'Select Team Projects...' link at the top
>
> Select only the single project I am trying to check in

But the error is still stopping a check in?

**UPDATE**

Please see the image of the error when trying to commit to a different project

[image: tfs issue 1]

more concerning is the fact when I try to connect to source control is get a 404 error. see the screenshot below.

[image: tfs issue 2]

Now just to note, the image I uploaded suggests there are no changes to commit (even though I have added a comment to a couple of files as a test). I also then edited a further file which now appears as a file to be included in the commit, however, the same message above is still appearing.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

1. Change the workspace configuration and map only the one project you're working on.
2. In the Pending Changes panel of Team Explorer temporarily exclude the items you don't want to check in at this moment
3. Undo the pending changes on the other project
4. Add a `.tfIgnore` file which excludes the files in bin directories by default (which may be something you'd want to do in any case).

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jesse. I removed it as above but it still gave the same message? Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's a bit unclear which of the 4 routes you chose. Can you update the question with what you did, optionally add screenshort for clarity?

Comment: hi jesse, as requested I added some screen, i think the problem may lie a little deeper, as I am now getting a 404 error when trying to view the source control section.